# How do I use a reaction handler with a switch statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord.js bot, and I'm creating a function that allows a user to react to a given message, then the bot will edit the message depending on the reaction.

What I made works, however, I want the user to be able to press the reaction more than once before it ends. Here is my code:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) =>
 ['', '', '', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) &&
 user.id === message.author.id;
```

```js
r.awaitReactions(filter, {
 max: 3,
 time: 30000,
 errors: ['time'],
})
 .then((collected) => {
  const reaction = collected.first();
  switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
   case '':
    message.util.send(cAbility);
    break;
   case '':
    message.util.send(qAbility);
    break;
   case '':
    message.util.send(eAbility);
    break;
   case '':
    message.util.send(ultAbility);
    break;
  }
 })
 .catch((collected) => {
  return console.log();
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to listen for reactions instead of awaiting them.

Here's an example:

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.partial) {
    // The message the reaction belongs to might have been deleted.
    try {
      await reaction.fetch();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error: ', error);
      return;
    }
  }
  switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
   case '':
    message.util.send(cAbility);
    break;
   case '':
    message.util.send(qAbility);
    break;
   case '':
    message.util.send(eAbility);
    break;
   case '':
    message.util.send(ultAbility);
    break;
  }
})
```